# Fixing an audio card shorted capacitor with software solution

Tags: audio

Recently one of the capacitors on [my MB](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/970%20Extreme4/) in the integrated Realtek HD audio card shorted. I cannot identify and solder another capacitor, because they are very tiny SMD elements. Despite this being a hardware problem, it can be fixed using audio filter software. I am having an FFT peak at 9322Hz and when I generate a 180-degree shifted digital sinewave using [my personal copy of the soundcard scope software](https://www.zeitnitz.eu/scope_en), the peak in the FFT graph disappears. I need a program which can:

1. Create custom amplitude-frequency graph to cut-off the 9 KHz using low-pass and high-pass filters.
2. Prefer to be an open-source project, so I can contribute, but an end-user program is also OK.
3. Processes the data from the sound card, so I can use its output to loop back the audio.
4. Sits and interacts between the application making a request to the sound card and the sound card itself.
5. Sends the filtered audio to the sound card rather than the original audio
6. I can easily design a filter, but I lack the program which can interface my filter design.

I can provide more information in 3-4 hours.

Comment: Why not just buy a $10 USB sound card and use that instead of the onboard sound?

Comment: The link to "personal copy of soundcard software" is flagged as unsafe by Microsoft SmartScreen.

Comment: @alephzero It's just a program called `Soundcard Oscilloscope` written in Pascal by `Christian Zeitnitz` in this website. I have a personal license registration.

https://www.zeitnitz.eu/scope_en

Comment: If I wanted to buy another card to fix the problem, I'd rather go for an expensive ones like [Creative](https://us.creative.com/p/sound-cards/sound-blaster-zx) all together. I want to know is there a program that can I do proper filtering with, without buying a new card and just cut off the 9 kHz